# Echo returns array instead of value

Tags: php, mysql

My echo returns Array instead of value.

```
$postscount = mysql_query('select count(authorid) from topics where authorid="'.$author.'" ');
$posts = mysql_fetch_row($postscount);
```

Here's echo:

```
{
echo "Posts: ".$posts." ";
}
```

I tried with this:

```
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($posts);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

with print_r it retuns this:

> Array (
>       [0] => 73 )

and with var_dump()

> array(1) {   [0]=>   string(2) "73" }

Comment: tried with print_r and got what?

Comment: maybe you have an empty array, try with `var_dump()`

Comment: `My echo returns Array` and this is right.

Comment: You [shouldn't use mysql_* functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$postscount = mysql_query('select count(authorid) from topics where authorid="'.$author.'" ') or die(mysql_error());
$posts = mysql_fetch_row($postscount);
var_dump($posts);
echo "There are ".$posts[0]. " authors";
```

Here

```
or die(mysql_error())
```

will tell you that query was successful or not.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "73" }

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
echo $posts[0]['count(authorid)'];
```

Or just like

```
echo $posts[0];
```

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'count(authorid)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Forum\read_topic.php on line 100
7

Comment: Then remove `'count(authorid)'`

Answer (score 0):

Use this to print your complete array :

```
echo '<pre>'.var_export($posts, true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: array (
  0 => '73',
)

Comment: Yeah ? expected result so ??

Comment: I want it to return 73

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli

```
$posts = $name = $mysqli->query('select count(authorid) as postcount from topics where authorid="'.$author.'" ')->fetch_object()->postcount;  
echo $posts;
```

See more on PHP.net http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php